# Does importing a namespace package also import the modules in the directory?

Tags: python, namespace-package

[This](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#importing-packages) explanation of package imports says that importing a package `packB` without an `__init__.py` file doesn't do anything because `__init__.py` tells the import process what other `*.py` files to import.

I'm at a loss as to how that is useful.  I'm a Python newbie, but everything I've read online says that such an "implicit namespace package" lacks `__init__.py` files because there may be *multiple* `packB` folders whose contents are to be combined into a common `packB` namespace.

Is this simply an error in the page cited above, or is there a clearer explanation that I just haven't found?

Comment: It's not useful. You're not supposed to use `import packB`. You can use `import packB.b1` or `packB.b2` to import individual files in that directory.

Comment: Sorry, now I'm more confused. [This](https://dev.to/bastantoine/discovering-python-namespace-packages-4gi3) page seems to indicate that you need to import the namespace package and namespace subpackages before you can import `*.py` modules contained in the latter. I'm looking specifically at the section *Step by step basic example*, the paragraph that starts with "And *now* we can import both `foo` and `bar` modules under the same package name..." The italicization is my own.

Comment: This is written a bit misleading. It just means: when you have prepared the files and directories in the given structure and set the Python search path accordingly, you can import the modules. It is not related to importing the package.

Comment: That article imports one level at a time because the author wants to display each level's `__path__` metadata. You don't need to import one level at a time, and if you read further down, you'll find cases where the article doesn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. My brain was fried trying to track the
rules of importing, especially for namespace packages, and wasn't
ready to tackle new concepts like "Dynamic loading of package parts".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages may have optional modules that are only imported as needed. It would be bad form for python to automatically import everything in a package, just in case.

Originally packages where required to have an `__init__.py` and that module was imported as the package namespace. This was deemed important so that a parent directory in `sys.path` could also hold non-python subdirectories without confusion. The `__init__.py` gave the package writer a place to import any modules it deemed necessary at package import.

But the desire to split a package into multiple deliverables made that requirement more difficult - which of these deliverables would hold the required `__init__.py`. Eventually, this second usage won out.

Now, if you have a directory with .py files in it, but no `__init__.py`, python will import it as an empty namespace. It's not useless, because it still gives a parent namespace for the other modules in the package, even if they need their own import.

If I have

```
foo/
    time.py
```

the empty "foo" still differentiates my optionally-imported `foo.time` module from the standard library `time` module. `import foo` may only be marginally useful, but `import foo.time` is not. `import foo` has the marginal advantage of testing that the `foo` is installed on this system without any assumptions about which deliverables have been installed.

Comment: Suppose (1) `sys.path` includes `/Some/Path`; (2) namespace package
`/Some/Path/NmSpcPkg` contains namespace subpackage
`/Some/Path/NmSpcPkg/NmSpcSbPkg`; and (3) module
`/Some/Path/NmSpcPkg/NmSpcSbPkg/SomeModule.py` contains function
`SomeFunc`. Can I `from NmSpcPkg.NmSpcSbPkg.SomeFunc import SomeFunc`
without any previously importing `NmSpcPkg` or `NmSpcSbPkg`?

Comment: @user2153235 there was a minor misspelling there, but `from NmSpcPkg.NmSpcSbPkg.SomeModule import SomeFunc` works. Python attempts the import of each component starting with `NmSpcPkg` and going to the right.

Comment: Thanks!  I can't edit the comment anymore, so I hope any readers see your correction.  I went through quite a few online descriptions without having clarity on this.  Hopefully, your answer demystifies this for others too.